# How to Solve this (J2ME) : javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: error 0 in socket::open

Tags: java-me, database-connection, httpconnection

i am trying to insert Data in my DataBase using this Code but i'am getting an exception :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletStateChangeException;
import com.sun.lwuit.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;


public class MyMidlet extends MIDlet implements Runnable {

    Form f;
    TextField t1 ;
    Label label1 ;
    Button b1;


     TextField tfNom ;
     TextField tfPrenom ;


    //Connexion
    HttpConnection hc;
    DataInputStream dis;
    String url ;
    StringBuffer sb ;
    int ch;



    public MyMidlet() {
        Display.init(this); 
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {

        f = new Form("Test");




        tfNom = new TextField("nom : ");
        tfPrenom = new TextField("prenom :");

        b1=new Button("ok");


        f.addComponent(tfNom); // append
        f.addComponent(tfPrenom);
        f.addComponent(b1);


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("gooooo");

                url= "http://localhost/J2ME/ajout.php";
                sb = new StringBuffer();


                //****************************


                 try {
                     hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+"?nom="+tfNom.getText()+"&prenom="+tfPrenom.getText());
                     dis = new DataInputStream(hc.openDataInputStream());
                     while ((ch = dis.read()) != -1) {                    
                         sb.append((char)ch);

                     }
                     // trim tna77i les espaces 
                     if ("successfully added".equalsIgnoreCase(sb.toString().trim())) {


                     System.out.println("succes (added)");


                     }else{


                     System.out.println("Error While Adding Data");

                     }
                 } catch (IOException ex) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                 }


                //***********************               


            System.out.println("I am Ouuuut");


            }
        });

        f.show();

    }

    public void run() {

}
}
```

--> It does not work and I'am getting this exception : 
i'am using NOKIA DevEnv for the first time. It used to work when I use it on Normal Netbeans J2ME.
Can any one help ?

```
gooooo
javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException: error 0 in socket::open
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.open0(), bci=0
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.connect(), bci=143
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.open(), bci=122
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.socket.Protocol.openPrim(), bci=4
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.createConnection(), bci=13
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.connect(), bci=138
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.streamConnect(), bci=53
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.startRequest(), bci=7
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=33
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.sendRequest(), bci=3
 - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.openInputStream(), bci=6
 - com.sun.midp.io.ConnectionBaseAdapter.openDataInputStream(), bci=5
 - esprit.MyMidlet$1.actionPerformed(MyMidlet.java:89)
 - com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:312)
 - com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:257)
 - com.sun.lwuit.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:369)
 - com.sun.lwuit.Button.released(Button.java:400)
 - com.sun.lwuit.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:476)
 - com.sun.lwuit.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2059)
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:2065)
 - com.sun.lwuit.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:1643)
 - com.sun.lwuit.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:894)
 - com.sun.lwuit.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:839)
 - com.sun.lwuit.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:119)
 - java.lang.Thread.run(), bci=5
I am Ouuuut
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your application cannot connect to the internet or if it can, fails to connect to your web service using the link provided. Try entering the URL for your request in your web browser and see if it is reachable. If you are connecting to your web service through a specific port (eg. http://mylink.com:8085/my-web-service/), make sure that the specific port is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Mwai is right - the code provided tries to work with server at "http://localhost/J2ME/ajout.php" and obviously it doesn't exists. Probably the Netbeans project included server side code as well, which was deployed at localhost (user PC) and J2ME client connected to it from emulator.

You need to start server part somehow (it's specific to your project). In a real environment (not emulator) you will need to deploy the server part somewhere in internet and connect to it from app running on phone. So you will need to change url to that server. 'localhost' means a local server (your PC).